# Having trouble understanding what's happening in an R code snippet

Tags: r, dplyr

In the following code:

```
library(Lahman)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

# load the baseball Teams data frame
data(Teams)

# make a copy of the Teams data frame
teams_tab <- Teams

# add stolen bases per game and runs per game columns
teams_tab <- teams_tab %>%  mutate(sb_per_game = SB / G, runs_per_game = R / G)

summary <- teams_tab %>% 
  filter(yearID >= 1961) %>%
  group_by(yearID) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(runs_per_game ~ sb_per_game, data = .)))
```

I don't understand what `data = .` is doing in the `lm` function. I also noticed that `do(tidy(lm(.$runs_per_game ~ .$sb_per_game)))` also works but I don't understand why. Can someone please explain how what the dot operator is doing?

Comment: `.` refers to the result of the previous expression in the pipe.

Comment: This [*magrittr* vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) explains it as well.

Comment: The `data =` is telling the `lm` function to accept the "dot" as it's input data value for computing using the formula that is `lm`'s first argument. You need to review the introductory texts that you are using. What? you don't have any introductory texts? Then go get (and diligently read) some.

Comment: Thanks for the information Richard.  It turns out that the internet is my introductory text and I wasn't having much luck searching on what the dot operator does.  Thanks for the link to  magrittr vignette.

Comment: Richard, you should post an answer so I can accept the correct answer.